# DJango-tables2 how do I refresh/update the table on the webpage without hitting refresh button

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, django-tables2

I followed the DJango-tables2 [official tutorial](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/tutorial.html) and was able to create data set in the terminal using:

```
Person.objects.bulk_create([Person(name='Jieter'), Person(name='Bradley')])
```

However, the new data in the table  on the website doesn't show up until I hit the refresh button. My question is how the table can be updated/refreshed without any human interaction on the webpage.

What I'm trying to achieve is to update the table on the webpage without human interaction as soon as new data comes in. I'm relatively new to this, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid refreshing the page you would need to get new data using an Ajax request, this table use template rendering meaning it is not meant to work like you want to use it. 
Usually, to do what you want to do, you need a front end JavaScript component like Datatables.net, FancyGrid ... and make requests to server using Ajax to get new data.